# Picklist Values org to org migration using Ant Migration tool

Tags: picklist, migration

Hi I am working in a project that merge two Salesforce org into one. While migrating standard picklist values using the Ant Migration Tool, I can retrieve picklist values using the following package.xml definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account.AccountSource</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

Retrieve is fine but when to deploy, it inactivate all the standard picklist values in the target org and put all the picklist values from the retrieve folder.

How Can I migrate picklist values to become a unique set that will include all the value from source and target.